# Can anyone provide me sample excel load test report for JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone provide me sample excel load test report for JMeter?
As LoadRunner has nice reporting features in Word if such feature is available for JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert your jmeter output format to one that LaodRunner analysis can read and then use the LoadRunner tool (available as part of the community edition of LoadRunner) to generate your report?

Or, you can load the results into something like R, a statistical analysis package, and report your results out of there.

There is always the possibility of using LaTeX and outputting a PDF or website.

If seems like you have found the value of the commercial tool offering vs the open sourced one.

etc....